# How to make padding of arrow from right side in PickerRenderer xamarin forms IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
{
base.OnElementChanged(e);
if (this.Control != null)
{
var downarrow = UIImage.FromBundle("your image");
var textField = this.Control;
textField.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
textField.RightView = new UIImageView(downarrow);
}
}
}
```

I have using PickerRenderer for IOS and I want to make some space from right side.How to make padding from right side ? Here Image, please check [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Grid with image and picker.

```
<Grid> 
   <Picker/>
   <Image Source="arrow.png" HorizontalOptions="End" Magin="5"/> 
</Grid>
```

may be it's help you

Comment: yes, it is working but click event is not working on arrow.

Comment: Try This..
<Grid>   
   <Image Source="arrow.png" HorizontalOptions="End" Magin="5"/> 
   <Picker BackGroundColor="Transparent"/>
</Grid>

Comment: hide image in case of UWP. because UWP Provide default arrow in picker.

Answer (score 8):

Xamarin Picker Arrow Workaround

In addition to @Pratik post, Clicking on the arrow won't work unless you make tapped event for the image.

**XAML**

```
            <Grid>
                <Picker
                    x:Name="catPicker"
                    Title="Select Type"/>
                <Image
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="down_arrow">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Arrow_OnTapped" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
```

**C#**

```
    private void Arrow_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        catPicker.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom renderer that allows you to add padding on the right side of an image for a picker...

It is applicable for an Entry Element

```
public class DefaultPickerRender : PickerRenderer
{
    CALayer bottomLine;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var element = (DefaultPicker)this.Element;

        if (this.Control != null && this.Element != null && (element.Image != null))
        {
             var viewPadding = new UIView(frame: new CGRect(x: -10, y: 0, width: 12, height: 12));
            var imageView = new UIImageView(frame: new CGRect(-10, 0, width: 12, height: 12));

            imageView.Center = viewPadding.Center;
            imageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(element.Image);

            viewPadding.AddSubview(imageView);
            Control.RightView = viewPadding;

          
            Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
            //  Control.RightView = downarrow; //new UIImageView(downarrow);


            Control.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 10, 0));
            Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

            if (element.IsTransparent)
                Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            else
                Control.BackgroundColor = (new UIColor(red: 0.10f, green: 0.10f, blue: 0.10f, alpha: 1.00f)).ColorWithAlpha((nfloat)0.03); //#191919


            bottomLine = new CALayer();
            bottomLine.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(bottomLine);

        }
    }


    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        bottomLine.Frame = new CGRect(0, Control.Frame.Height - 1, Control.Frame.Width, 2);
    }
}
```